# Bottom Navigation Material UI Override

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm trying to override the colour of the bottom navigation icon from material UI [here][1]. This is my css code:

```
.MuiButtonBase-root{
    color: #007A78;
}

.MuiBottomNavigationAction-root{
    color: #007A78;
}

.Mui-selected{
    color: #007A78;
}
```

I'm trying to change the default blue colour into my colour (green). However, I only notice the text changes colour, not the icon:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
I use the elements to see the css and apparently the colour doesn't change for the icon. It's still the same blue colour.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Does anyone know how to override this?
[1]: https://mui.com/api/bottom-navigation-action/
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG9DW.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/joxTL.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sx` to update the styling of the `bottom navigation` component from the [Material UI](https://mui.com/api/bottom-navigation-action/). You can style the classes individually to apply different styles based on the UI.

```
sx={{
   "& .MuiBottomNavigationAction-root, .Mui-selected, svg": {
     color: "#007A78"
   }
}}
```

to style only the active navigation item, you can target the `.Mui-selected` class as below

```
sx={{
    "& .Mui-selected, .Mui-selected > svg": {
      color: "#007A78"
    }
}}
```

Complete code [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/simplebottomnavigation-material-demo-forked-xmbs6?file=/demo.tsx:676-802)

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import BottomNavigation from "@mui/material/BottomNavigation";
import BottomNavigationAction from "@mui/material/BottomNavigationAction";
import RestoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Restore";
import FavoriteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import LocationOnIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LocationOn";

export default function SimpleBottomNavigation() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 500 }}>
      <BottomNavigation
        showLabels
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        sx={{
          "& .MuiBottomNavigationAction-root, .Mui-selected, svg": {
            color: "#007A78"
          }
        }}
      >
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Recents" icon={<RestoreIcon />} />
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Favorites" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Nearby" icon={<LocationOnIcon />} />
      </BottomNavigation>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: In that case, all 3 tabs will have the same colour, I want the icon turns green when the user clicks on that tab :(

Comment: If I leave the "Mui-selected" only, only the texts changes colour, the icons are the same, but if I leave the "svg" as well, all the icons have the same colour

Comment: Do you want the green color for only `active` item for label and icon? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simplebottomnavigation-material-demo-forked-xmbs6?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: sweet as! thanks for your help! I'm quite new to these haha!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<paper sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }} elevation={3}>
```

if you are trying to make a bottom navigation.