# How to style Material-UI's BottomNavigationAction, so the selected icon is a different color?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I need some help with this problem I'm having with Material-UI styled components

I'm trying to create a BottomNavigation bar on react using Material-UI v5. I want that the icon of the selected option in the bar shows a specific color, let's say red (#f00) and the not-selected icons show green (#00f), for this I'm using the `styled` function to generate a custom-themed component for BottomNavigationAction, following the guidelines on the documentation: [styled()](https://mui.com/system/styled/). **The problem:** For the selected button, the icon is not grabbing the correct color and is showing the default one. At this point I'm not sure if I'm using the `styled` function wrong or is something super obvious I'm not seeing. Thanks in advance for any advice!

PS: I don't have enough reputation to post the image directly, sorry for that

The BottomNavigation is defined as follows:

```js
const BottomNav = () => {
        return(
            <BottomNavigation
                showLabels
                value={value}
                onChange={(event, newValue) => {setValue(newValue)}}
            >                
                <TabBarButton 
                    id='Home' 
                    label='Home' 
                    icon= {home_icon? <AiFillHome size = "30" />: <AiOutlineHome size='30'/> } 
                    onClick={
                        (value)=>{
                            iconHandler(value.currentTarget.id)
                        }
                    }
                />

                <TabBarButton
                    id='Documentos' 
                    label='Documentos' 
                    icon= {documentos_icon? <RiEditBoxFill size='30'/>: <RiEditBoxLine size='30'/>} 
                    onClick={
                        (value) =>
                            iconHandler(value.currentTarget.id)
                        }
                    }
                />
            </BottomNavigation>
        );
    }
```

To define `TabBarButton` I  firstly tried defining the component like this:

```js
import {BottomNavigation, BottomNavigationAction} from "@mui/material";
import { styled} from '@mui/system';

// Styled BottomNavigationAction
const TabBarButton = styled(BottomNavigationAction)({
    root: {
        color: '#f00',
    },
    
    selected: {
        color: '#0f0',
    }
});
```

But the rule names: `root` and `selected` didn't work, resulting in the default colors being applied:
[first-try-bottom-navigation-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n85c4.png)

So I changed them to the Global Class instead : [BottomNavigationAction CSS](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/bottom-navigation-action/#css) :

```js
// Styled BottomNavigationAction
const TabBarButton = styled(BottomNavigationAction)({
    color: '#0f0',
    '.Mui-selected':{
        color: '#f00',
    }
});
```

Which worked with the not-selected icon and the labels:

[second-try-bottom-navigation-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5bUT.png)

But the selected icon 'Home' is still using the default colors, I tried using a variation of the answer provided on this post [Bottom Navigation Material UI Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458713/bottom-navigation-material-ui-override)

```js
// Styled BottomNavigationAction
const TabBarButton = styled(BottomNavigationAction)({
    color: '#0f0',
    '.Mui-selected, svg':{
        color: '#f00',
    }
});
```

But this affects both icons resulting in :

[third-try-bottom-navigation-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0eO3.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `TabBarButton` need to add `'&.Mui-selected'` selector to have the styles attached to itself correctly, otherwise with `'.Mui-selected'` the rules only apply to nested elements:

Tested the example on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vwdmwa?file=src/App.js)

```
// Styled BottomNavigationAction
const TabBarButton = styled(BottomNavigationAction)({
  color: 'royalblue',
  '&.Mui-selected': {
    color: 'crimson',
  },
});
```